# I am unable to find whats wrong with the post request its not sending to the "/add " and not even updating it on the card veiw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

this is the main index.html.erb code
I am unable to find whats wrong with the post request its not sending to the "/add " and not even updating it on the card veiw .

```
<%= render "header" %>
<form method="POST" action="/add">
<%=token_tag%>
<div class="col-6" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="titleid" class="form-label">TITLE</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleid" name="title" placeholder="text">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="descriptionid" class="form-label">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="descriptionid" name="description" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  <!-- this closing div tag was missing -->
  <div class="mb-3">
      <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" style="display:block;margin:0 auto">
</div>
</div>   
  </form>
<hr>

<% Post.all.each do |post| %>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><%post.title %> </h5>
      <p class="card-text"> <%post.description %></p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "footer" %>
```

#this is index.html.erb
I am unable to find whats wrong with the post request its not sending to the "/add " and not even updating it on the card veiw .

```
class RootController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @post=Post.all
        render "index"
    end
    def contact
        
        render "contact"

    end
    def about
       
        render "about"

    end
    
 

    def api
        @response={
            :status => 200,
            :message => "helllow world"
        }
        render json: @response
    end
    def user
        # render json:params[:name]
        render json:params
    end
    def add
    @post=Post.new
    @post.title=params[:title]
    @post.description=params[:description]
    @post.save
    @response={
        :status => 200,
        :message => " sucessfully created"
    }
    @posts=Post.all
    render "index"
    

    end

   
end
```

this is routcontroller

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  root "root#index" 
  post '/add' ,to:"root#add"
  get '/contact',to: "root#contact"
  get '/about' ,to: "root#about"
  # get '/index',to: "root#index"
  get '/response',to: "root#api"
  get '/user/:id/:name' , to:"root#user" 
  # get '/add',to: "root#add"
  
 

 
end
```

this is root.rb

Comment: What's in the server logs?

Comment: Change `@post.save` to `@post.save!` which will raise an error when not being able to save the record telling you why it was unable.

Comment: Don't you need to whitelist (permit) the post params somewhere?

Comment: I think what you actually should do here is backtrack and follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and just learn the basics of CRUD in Rails. Once you have figured this out then you can learn how to bend the conventions and place a form on the index view instead. The code you have written here isn't actually Rails code. It's just code that happens to be using Rails.

Comment: can you please make it more clear i am new to ruby